# how to merge array dynamic values with same index with same array name

Tags: php

I have defined one array and one variable total marks in total marks i am getting the sum of student subject marks and each time i am storing in array. That array is assigned with same index.
1. I want to store all total marks in one array with different index.

```
<?php

$record = array();

$total_marks = 0;

foreach ($result_detail as $key3 => $value8) {

    $total_marks += $value8['get_marks'];
    $record[$key3] =  $total_marks;

    array_merge($record,$record);
}

?>
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 97
)
Array
(
    [0] => 45
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
)
```

but i want with different index after merging

Comment: Can you shor `print_r($result_detail)` here?

Comment: Array
(
    [id] => 834
    [session_id] => 0
    [attendence] => P
    [student_id] => 48
    [exam_scheduled_id] => 90
    [get_marks] => 15
    [total_rank] => 
    [created_at] => 2019-10-26 13:15:13
    [updated_at] => 2019-10-26 13:15:13
)
Array
(
    [id] => 835
    [session_id] => 0
    [attendence] => P
    [student_id] => 48
    [exam_scheduled_id] => 91
    [get_marks] => 59
    [total_rank] => 
    [created_at] => 2019-10-26 13:15:13
    [updated_at] => 2019-10-26 13:15:13
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple replace `$record[$key3] =  $total_marks;` with $`record[] =  $total_marks;`. It will generate key automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this if need different index

```
        $record = array();

        $total_marks = 0;

        foreach ($result_detail as $key3 => $value8) {

             $total_marks += $value8['get_marks'];

              $record[] =  $total_marks;






                }



?>
```

Comment: then also i am getting same result Array
(
    [0] => 97
)
Array
(
    [0] => 45
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
)